Error certificate has expired or is not yet valid trying to install docker image with Container Station on Qnap
I build a docker image on my 32bit qnap and upload to DockerHub using command line docker, that seems to be fine
But now when i try and install the image from DockerHub using the Container Station Gui
I get this error

Background task error for create songkong-arm32: error pulling image
configuration: Get
https://production.cloudflare.docker.com/registry-v2/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/18/18d9aad83fd25325c79c6effe8ee828d8f0626eeefd875d75fe1527b698873d9/data?verify=1714748301-c83RWCZwcBfrUhejo9lVykWPzeU%3D:
x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid

Is this an issue with my docker build, or an issue with my qnap nas ?

I suggest you to check date and time on the machine you are trying to download the image

This seems to be a problem of your qnap.
Try to update your certificate:

Show and save certificate of production.cloudflare.docker.com

echo | openssl s_client -servername production.cloudflare.docker.com -connect production.cloudflare.docker.com:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -text > production.cloudflare.docker.com.crt


Move to certifiacte folder

cat production.cloudflare.docker.com.crt >> /share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/.qpkg/container-station/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

# or

cp production.cloudflare.docker.com.crt /share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/.qpkg/container-station/etc/ssl/certs


Update

update-ca-certificate

# or

/etc/init.d/container-station.sh restart

